# react-scripts required old version of webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I installed *webpack* into my react project, but the same error occurred every time when I use ***npm start***:

> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.42.0"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
>   However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
>
> C:\react\minimoj\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.43.0)

I tried to remove package-loc.json file + all node_modules + remove *webpack* name from package.json and reinstall it with ***npm install***. Also I tried same with yarn, but it didn't help. I see that in *node_modules* version is 4.43 and after I use ***npm install webpack*** in the file package-loc.json it shows 4.43, but at the moment when I use ***npm start*** it changed to 4.42 and error occur. In addition I also reinstall node.js but it didn't help.

Comment: What version of react-scripts do you use? Try updating to 3.4.1.

Comment: I have version 3.4.1 :)

Comment: Actually, why do you want to install webpack in the first place? It is preconfigured and hidden in create-react-app. If you want to access the config files, you need to eject by running "npm run eject".

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. I try to install webpack because for some reason all my .css files did not load into components and I thought it's because webpack doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar with a newer webpack version being installed than what react_scripts required.
To fix I deleted webpack and webpack-dev-server from my project's node_modules, went to a console **outside of the project dir** and ran

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
```

Then ran

```
npm install
npm run build
```

And all was well, as my package.json was correct without change.

Comment: I had a global webpack version installed, removing that fixed the issue for me (`npm ls webpack` was also helpful)

Answer (score 3):

create .env file and add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true

Answer (score 0):

Since webpack is mostly focused on common js according to some websites, I just tried rollup for my react project and it proved to be much more effective as it supports es+. I would highly recommend it. I took a couple minutes to have everything setup and ready. Also, as a good practice it is better to use yarn as npm has had a lot of known issues for node app management.